# ANDROID listview item on long click start changing height as finger moves

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener, gesturedetector

ANDROID - I want to implement a feature where on long click of listview row I should be able to change the height of the row (so basically a scroll) and otherwise the list should scroll naturally.

Can someone tell me the steps to do this, I want this thing in the listview adapter. but it is giving problems with scrolling.

Can anyone suggest any steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a demo,try like this

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.width=200;
            params.height=200;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);        
        }
    });
```